# using mongo aggregation how to replace the fields names

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my mongodb query, using  $match i got the last 24 hours records of each_pm10_avg valus it's fine but how to replace output fields names.any one help me

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {CREATEDATE: {$gt: new Date(new 

    Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24))}}},
     {$project: {  "HOUR":{"$hour":"$CREATEDATE"}, "PM10":1 }},

     {$group:{ "_id":{"HOUR":"$HOUR"}, "PM10":{$avg:"$PM10"} }},


    ])


  output:
{
    "_id" : {
        "HOUR" : 17
    },
    "PM10" : 600.361389160156
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "HOUR" : 16
    },
    "PM10" : 179.824882507324
}
expected output:
```

{
        "_id" : {
            "HOUR" : 17
        },
        "series":"PM10",
        "AVG" : 600.361389160156
    }

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "HOUR" : 16
    },
     "series":"PM10",
    "AVG" : 179.824882507324
}
```

Comment: `{$group:{ "_id":{"HOUR":"$HOUR"}, "series": { "$first": "PM10" }, "AVG":{$avg:"$PM10"} }},` Just call the fields what you want them to be in your final output stage. For an arbitrary value you can just supply a "string" to an accumulator, such as `$first`.

Comment: iam trying this output is {
    "_id" : {
        "HOUR" : 16
    },
    "series" : "series",
    "AVG" : 179.824882507324
}
how to replace "series" : "series", to "series" : "PM10", any possible

Comment: Look at the line again.

Comment: Marking as duplicate to prevent adding of answers saying to add a  `$project` like the duplicate does. But putting a literal in the `$group` is what you should do when it's the last stage. Also `{ "$group": { "_id": { "HOUR": { "$hour":"$CREATEDATE" } }, "series": { "$first": "PM10" }, "AVG":{ "$avg": "$PM10" } }}` is all you need and you don't need the `$project`

Comment: @ Neil Lunn  thank you...